# Cocoa Error 513 when trying to write to normal directories

Tags: iphone, ios, file-io

I'm simply trying to create a secure user file that will save basic login information so it does not need to be typed in every time the app launches.  I know I cannot write to the bundle, so I am trying one of the other directories we are supposed to have access to, like caches, documents, and library, none of these have resulted in a successful write

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, NO);
    NSString *cacheDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"Found cache directory: %@", cacheDirectory);
    NSString *fileName = [cacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"987f065e4656dba6c"];
    NSString *userData = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@", owner.schoolWebsite.text, owner.username.text, owner.password.text];
    NSError *fileError = nil;
    if(!([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:cacheDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&fileError]))
    {
        NSLog(@"Error creating cache directory: %@\n%@\n%@\n%@", [fileError localizedDescription], [fileError localizedFailureReason], [fileError localizedRecoveryOptions], [fileError localizedRecoverySuggestion]);
    }        
    if (!([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileName contents:[userData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] attributes:nil] ) )

    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR WRITING TO FILE: %@\n%@\n%@\n%@", [fileError localizedDescription], [fileError localizedFailureReason], [fileError localizedRecoveryOptions], [fileError localizedRecoverySuggestion]);
    }
```

this has been plaguing me for a while, and this only fails on the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, NO);
```

wit this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

I've replaced `NSLibraryDirectory` (/Library) with `NSCachesDirectory` (/Library/Cache). Also denoted to expand tilde to full path which probably is the main cause behind this.

Comment: That did it, thank you.  I'm not sure why they would have that be an option if it doesn't work if you specify "NO"